# How to use CSS to create a dynamic corner frame?

Tags: html, css, border

How can I use CSS to create a dynamic corner frame as shown in this picture below?[image]

Below is my current solution, but it is not dynamic enough as I have two contents with two different width,

```
    <p class="description-header">
        <span class="frame-header frame-header-top"></span>
        <span class="description-text"><?php echo $home->excerpt;?></span>
        <span class="frame-header frame-header-bottom"></span>
    </p>
```

css,

```
.description-header {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:182px;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:14px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0 solid red;
}

.frame-header {
    display:block;
    width:182px;
    height:10px;
    float:none;
    background-image:url(../images/frame-header.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin:0;
    border:0 solid red;
}

.frame-header-top {
    background-position: top left;
}

.frame-header-bottom {
    background-position: bottom left;
}

.description-text {
    width:160px;
    display:block;
    float:none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border:0 solid red;
}
```

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an aggressively pure CSS solution, using only 1 HTML elements, a frame (wrapper) and the content, which I'm assuming is a single paragraph. [Check it out on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K9nAb/1/).

The idea is to use `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements on the 2 HTML elements to add the corners. 2 pseudo elements for 2 HTML elements allows us to create 4 corners.

I've only tested it in Chrome and Firefox.

---

Edit: I changed up the CSS so it's a little more generic, and will still work if you have more than one paragraph of content in there, or [a heading followed by paragraphs](http://jsfiddle.net/K9nAb/2/) or [even just spans](http://jsfiddle.net/K9nAb/3/).

## The HTML

```
<div class="frame">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor...
    </p>   
    <p>
        Mauris bibendum mauris non
    </p>
</div>
```

## The CSS

```
.frame {
    position:relative;
    padding:5px;
}
.frame:before {
    height:10px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    border-left:1px solid black;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    content: " ";
}
.frame:after {
    height:10px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    border-left:1px solid black;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    content: " ";
}
.frame > p {
    text-align:justify;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.frame :first-child:before {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:10px;
    border-top:1px solid black;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    content: " ";
}

.frame :first-child:after {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:10px;
    border-top:1px solid black;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    content: " ";
}
```

Comment: this is beautiful. Thank you! Is it a CSS3 solution? Would it work in IE?

Comment: Seems to work in IE9 - but I wouldn't put my money on it working in older IEs. Also, I made some edits so the CSS is more independent of the HTML.

Comment: And I do believe that pseudo-elements are part of CSS 2 - see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-elements

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like this:

html:

```
<p class="description-header">
    <?php echo $home->excerpt;?></span>
</p>
```

css:

```
.description-header{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:182px;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:14px;
    margin:0;
    border:0 solid red;
    background: url(../images/frame-header.jpg) left top no-repeat, url(../images/frame-header.jpg) left bottom no-repeat;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4QkYA/**

-- html --

```
<div class="frame">
    <div class="top-l"></div>
    <div class="top-r"></div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel/200/200/sports/2" alt=""/>
    <div class="bottom-l"></div>
    <div class="bottom-r"></div>
</div>
```

-- css --

```
img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
}

.frame {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.frame > div {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}

.top-l { top: 0; left: 0; }
.top-r { top: 0; right: 0; }
.bottom-l { bottom: 0; left: 0; }
.bottom-r { bottom: 0; right: 0; }
```